# installment - float error C2296

Tags: c++

I have this function:

```
    float ObliczRate(float fKwotaKredytu, float fOprocentowanie, int iIloscRat)
{
    /*
    Rata = K * y^n * (y-1) / (y^n-1);

    y = 1 + (r / 12)
    */

    float fRata, float fY;

    fY = 1 + (fOprocentowanie / 12); // obliczanie stałej kredytu
    fRata = fKwotaKredytu * fY^iIloscRat * (fY - 1) / (fY^iIloscRat - 1); // obliczanie raty stałej ze wzoru

    return fRata;
}
```

And i have error: "error C2296: '^' : illegal, left operand has type 'float'" only on "(fY^iIloscRat - 1)". What's wrong with this?

Comment: Polish comments. Oh yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `^` is *not* an exponential operator, but the bitwise XOR operator. You want the [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ the operator `^` has a meaning of bitwise XOR operator not the power operation. You will have to use the `pow` function defined in the `cmath` header here.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you have to use a function `pow` to do a power operation.

The signature looks like this:

```
float pow( float base, float exp );
```

You can find it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the pow function for this purpose. Below is the link to the example

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/